# Little doubt in the proof of theorem" If f is analytic on $\mathbb D$, , then there exist analytic function h such that $h^2=f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have one little doubt in the proof of following theorem which I am reading from one article.

Notation: $\mathbb D = \{ z \in \mathbb C :  |z| < 1\}$

Theorem: If f is analytic on  $\mathbb D$, with $0 \notin f(\mathbb D)$, then there exist analytic function h on $\mathbb D$ such that $h^2=f$.

The proof starts like this. They have defined new function g on $\mathbb D$ as follows:

Take $g(0)$ such that $e^{g(0)}=f(0)$, and for other w in $\mathbb D$, define $g(w)= g(0)+\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$, where $\gamma$ is smooth curve from $0$ to $w$. Then, clearly we have $g'(w)=\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}$ and thus $g'(z)$ is well defined for all $z \in \mathbb D$, and thus $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb D$. Now here is my little doubt. Their explanation does not justify why $g$ is analytic at $0$, i.e. why $g$ is differentiable at $0$. Can someone help me out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let the smooth curve be $\gamma(t) = tw, t\in [0,1].$ Then

$$\frac{g(w)-g(0)}{w} = \frac{1}{w}\int_0^1 \frac{f'(tw)}{f(tw)}w\,dt=\int_0^1 \frac{f'(tw)}{f(tw)}\,dt.$$

As $w\to 0,$ the last integral $\to \dfrac{f'(0)}{f(0)}$ by the continuity of $f'/f$ at $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f (0) \neq 0$ so there exists $r>0$ such that $|f(z)| >r$ whenever $|z|$ is sufficiently small. Now verify that $g(w) \to g(0)$as $w \to 0$ by estimating the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac {f'(z)} {f(z)}dz$. This implies that $g$ is necessarily analytic at $0$ also.

[Boundedness of $g$ in a neighborhood of $0$ implies that it has a removable singularity at $0$ and continuity now implies that $g$ is analytic at $0$].

Comment: i am little confused how $e^{g(0)}=f(0)$ fits perfectly in the picture

Comment: @Believer Your $h$ is $e^{g/2}$. You get the right value of $g'$ even if you  add an extra constant to the definition above, but you need $h(0)^{2}=f(0)$ or $e^{g(0)/2}=f(0)$. That is where the arbitrary constant in the definition of $G$ needs to be given a speicfic value. (Note that since $f(0) \neq 0$ we can always choose a complex number $c$ with $e^{c}=f(0)$).

Comment: thanks for all the help